# Matlab: How to set the email alert when the run finished?

Tags: matlab, email, alert

What code should I use in Matlab to have an email alert when a run is finished?
I've looked in the Matlab help but can't find any answers that match what I'm looking for, so I'm stuck.
https://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2134-can-matlab-send-out-alert-email-message-if-certain-variable-exceed-the-threshold
Thank you.

Comment: Shameless plug: try my MailSpoon Matlab library if you want the email alerts to be nicely formatted. https://github.com/janklab/MailSpoon. You can also just use that as code examples of how to send email from Matlab.

Comment: @Andrew Janke, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MATLAB has a built in command to send emails [sendmail](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sendmail.html).

If I were you I would just include something like this at the end of my script:

```matlab
sendmail('user@otherdomain.com','My subject', ...
        ['The script has finished' 10 'Regards' 10 ...
         'Me']);  % 10 are line breaks in this case
```

If your script does not have a fixed exit point and possibly error, then I would suggest you use the [onCleanup](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) class. It is a handy class that can execute a user-defined function upon a function or script end. You could use it to `sendmail` and/or do any other notification you need.